# Nested do-while loop inside a while loop

Tags: c++, nested-loops

Started to learn C++ and encountered an issue with a task.
The task requires me to rewrite a nested for loop to a do-while loop inside a while loop. The outputs are very different so I think I did something wrong.
The nested for loop:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  main()
  {
     int i, j;
     for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {   /* outer loop */
         printf("The start of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
         for (j=1; j<=4; j++)  /* inner loop */
         printf("Iteration %d of the inner loop.\n", j);
     printf("The end of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

output:

```
The start of iteration 1 of the outer loop.
    Iteration 1 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 2 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 3 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 4 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 1 of the outer loop.
The start of iteration 2 of the outer loop.
    Iteration 1 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 2 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 3 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 4 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 2 of the outer loop.
The start of iteration 3 of the outer loop.
    Iteration 1 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 2 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 3 of the inner loop.
    Iteration 4 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 3 of the outer loop.
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i, j;
    i = 1;
    j = 1;

    while (i <= 3) {
        printf("The start of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
        do {
            printf("Iteration %d of the inner loop.\n", j);
            j++;
        } while (j <= 4);
        printf("The end of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
The start of iteration 1 of the outer loop.
Iteration 1 of the inner loop.
Iteration 2 of the inner loop.
Iteration 3 of the inner loop.
Iteration 4 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 1 of the outer loop.
The start of iteration 2 of the outer loop.
Iteration 5 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 2 of the outer loop.
The start of iteration 3 of the outer loop.
Iteration 6 of the inner loop.
The end of iteration 3 of the outer loop.
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: you don't initialize j in its loop.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `j` to 1 in your second setup. So you keep incrementing it higher and the inner loop only runs once since it doesn't satisfy your loop condition.

You could add that like:

```
while (i <= 3) {
    printf("The start of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
    j = 1;
    // ^^^
    do {
        printf("Iteration %d of the inner loop.\n", j);
        j++;
    } while (j <= 4);
    printf("The end of iteration %d of the outer loop.\n", i);
    i++;
}
```